How to make Pulseaudio retain HDMI sink after various events
I have a display that provides also audio via HDMI/DP cable. I also have a USB audio adapter that is connected directly to computer. Sometimes I want to use HDMI audio, sometimes USB. The problem is that when I use HDMI audio, and choose to change display mode  or use display power management (maybe automatically), Pulseaudio switches to use the USB device, and does not switch back to the HDMI device after I unlock/resume. If HDMI audio was selected, I want it to use the same audio output after it comes available again after such events.
